# MySql: Preserving order in UNION ALL result

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union

I have the following:

```
with
result1 as ( select column1 from table1 order by ... )
result2 as ( select column1 from table2 order by ... )
select * from result1 union all select * from result2;
```

The intent is to list `result1` *with its order preserved* followed by `result2` *with its order preserved*.  However, it appears that `union all` does not preserve the order of its operand tables.  How can I get the intended effect?  I have tried adding columns to the ordered `result1` and `result2` and then order the union result on this added column, but this seems awfully klugy for something that seems pretty typical.   Is there anything like `union all ordered`?

Comment: Any resultset without an ORDER BY clause is unordered. The same applies to `select * from result1 union all select * from result2;`.

Comment: add to your ORDER BY a LIMIT 18446744073709551615  , so that the optimizer don't removes the order

Comment: Select 1 seq, other columns from table1 union select 2, other columns from table 2...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here is how you sort it out with "window functions". Provided you are using MySQL 8+

```
with
result1 as ( 
select column1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...) AS rownum1, 0 AS rownum2, 
from table1 order by ...
),
result2 as ( 
select column1, 0 AS rownum1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...) AS rownum2
from table2 order by ...
),
result as (
select * from result1 
union all
select * from result2 
)
     
select * from result order by rownum2, rownum1
```

Comment: What is the need of the internal ORDER BY clauses?

Comment: Also: *The intent is to list result1 with its order preserved followed by result2 with its order preserved* how does your code meet the requirement?

Comment: @forpas I edited the query. Order by, can be used at the last select only

Comment: Order by what? to preserve the order as described in the question/

Comment: @forpas Yes you are right. I edited the original answer. Now the query should work just as intent.

Comment: No it does not work and you can find out why if you read the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Comment: @forpas You are right again. I edited a solution for that. Look at my above suggested query !

Comment: Create a fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 with some sample data and you will see that your code does not even run.